# ¿Son duplicadas preguntas por errores de sintaxis?

Tags: discusión, duplicadas

Hay un número de preguntas respecto a un mismo error de sintaxis, pero con distintos códigos fuente, como estás:

- [int object is not callable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/401219/int-object-is-not-callable)
- [Python TypeError: 'int' object is not callable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/145295/python-typeerror-int-object-is-not-callable?rq=1)
- [TypeError: 'int' object is not callable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/259301/typeerror-int-object-is-not-callable)

La lista podría extenderse hasta el infinito con variaciones respecto al objeto en cuestión o el tipo de error (*not callable, not subscriptable, not iterable*), como estas:

- [TypeError: 'dict' object is not callable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/265989/typeerror-dict-object-is-not-callable?rq=1)
- [A que se debe el error TypeError: 'bool' object is not callable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/243826/a-que-se-debe-el-error-typeerror-bool-object-is-not-callable?rq=1)
- [Error '' 'bool' object is not subscriptable ''](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/120329/error-bool-object-is-not-subscriptable)
- [TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/311541/typeerror-int-object-is-not-iterable?rq=1)

Para mi son todas iguales: si entiendes por qué falla una, también entenderas el resto.
¿Son duplicadas o no?

Comment: Viendo que sucede tan seguido, haría una publicación canónica (si es que no hay una ya) que describa errores de sintaxis así como también errores más bien lógicos, la marcaría como wiki y marcaría todas las que apliquen como duplicados de esa nueva.

Comment: concuerdo... para estos casos, si el error es siempre claro, se puede hacer una canonica que las envuelva...

Comment: Son duplicadas... si hay alguna duplicada adonde apuntar

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existen *preguntas/respuestas canónicas* para otros temas similares: errores que a cualquier programador experto les resultan triviales y que se pueden dar con cualquier código, con lo que la respuesta es una guía para entender qué significa el error y cómo encontrar una solución.

Por ejemplo:

- [¿Cuál es la solución a todos los errores NullPointerException presentes, pasados y futuros?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/42977/cu%c3%a1l-es-la-soluci%c3%b3n-a-todos-los-errores-nullpointerexception-presentes-pasados)
- [¿Qué significa el error “Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set/read property 'XXX' of undefined/null” y cómo solucionarlo?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/169194/qu%C3%A9-significa-el-error-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-set-read-property-xxx-of-u)
- [¿Qué es una NullReferenceException y cómo solucionarla?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/75999/qu%C3%A9-es-una-nullreferenceexception-y-c%C3%B3mo-solucionarla)

Así que te animo a crear una pregunta respuesta similar para cualquier problema típico de compilación o error de ejecución que suela generar muchas preguntas. Estas preguntas al final son ruido, porque obligan a responder lo mismo una y otra vez, mientras que una respuesta genérica ayuda a los desarrolladores a pensar y analizar qué está pasando en su código.

Answer (score 1):

Realizar una publicación canónica hacia donde apuntar como duplicados es lo recomendado cuando no existe otra (como [respondió @PabloLozano](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4899/193460)).

Y @CandidMoe tomó la inciativa y publicó:
[Error: xxx Object is not callable. ¿Qué significa y cómo lo soluciono?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/401660/193460)